# Grep - print non matching words

Tags: awk, grep

I was trying to combine `-o` and `-v` with `grep`, but it doesn't work.

```
me@here:~$ echo -e "yes maybe possible\nno never nein"
yes maybe possible
no never nein
me@here:~$ echo -e "yes maybe possible\nno never nein"|grep -o "yes"
yes
me@here:~$ echo -e "yes maybe possible\nno never nein"|grep -v "yes"
no never nein
me@here:~$ echo -e "yes maybe possible\nno never nein"|grep -v -o "yes"
me@here:~$
```

I want a way to exclude the matching words, not lines (the thing you would expect by combining both `-v` and `-o`)

Comment: You should be using `... | sed 's/yes//g'`

Comment: @anubhava yes I know about using sed, but I was looking for an exclusively `grep` solution, `sed` would bring too much escaping hassle with my actual use case (words that contain any number of special characters interpreted by sed)

Comment: if escaping special characters is an issue then `awk` is best tool. `grep` performs line search, it is not meant for substitutions

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably use `awk`, only problem with is it the fact that I'd have to learn how to use it properly first :D

Comment: Could you show us your expected output? You say you want the output of what `-v` and `-o` combined give, but I don't understand what that would except what you see there.

Comment: @Lha If you want to "learn how to use it properly", then you've already succeeded. It's not a job for grep. `man grep` shows "print lines that match patterns". You want to print _all_ lines and transform (edit) some of them. That's a job for sed, awk, tr etc.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to achieve this with a Perl regular expression:

```
$ echo -e "yes maybe possible\nno never nein" | grep -Po '\b(?!yes\b)\w+'
maybe
possible
no
never
nein
```

It reads, find word-boundaries (`\b`) that are **not** followed by the word `yes` (negative lookahead `(?!yes\b)` but followed by a sequence of word_characters (`\w` equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_]`)

**note:** the OP tries to use `grep -v yes` which just matches substrings and not words itself. False positives could occur with words like 'polyester, eyesight, yesterday'. The `-W` flag for *whole word matches* is minimally needed.

Alternatively, you could make use of GNU awk:

```
$ echo -e "yes maybe possible\nno never nein" | awk 'BEGIN{RS="\\W+"}!($0=="yes")'
maybe
possible
no
never
nein
```

It reads: split the input in records which are words (record sepeartor is a sequence of non-word characters `RS="\\W+"`), if the record does not equal to "yes", print it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `gnu-awk` command that will handle all kind of special characters in input word to get you output skipping input word:

```sh
cat file

yes maybe possible
no never nein

awk -v s='yes' -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '$0 != s {ORS=RT; print}' file

maybe possible
no never nein
```

**Details:**

- `v s='yes'`: Is your input word
- `-v RS='[[:space:]]+'`: Sets input record separator as 1+ of any whitespace including line break so that each word is a record in `awk`
- `$0 != s`: When a word is not equal to input word `s`
- `ORS=RT`: Sets output record separator same as what we have found for `RS`
- `print`: Prints each record